# How can I create a Grid with it's X and Y axis bound to different collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, itemscontrol

I need to display something that shows a Week of days along the Columns, and a list of Categories along the Rows, and a list of Tasks that are due in the Cells (See sketch below)

I feel like the solution should be simple, but I'm drawing a blank as to how to bind such a thing.

Both the Rows, Columns, and data items in the Cells are dynamic based on what week the user is viewing, and ideally I'd like to hide categories that do not have any tasks for the currently viewed Week. I have collection properties for the currently Viewed Week, the list of Categories, and the list of Tasks, and each Task has a DueDate and Category associated with it....

[image: Task Scheduler Sketch]

**Edit**

My database looks like this:

**TASK TABLE**

```
TaskId
CategoryId
OtherProperties
```

**TASK INSTANCE TABLE**

```
TaskInstanceId
ParentTaskId
DueDate
```

I have a stored procedure that accepts a range of dates and returns a list of the following class (need to calculate recurring events)

```
TaskInstanceId
ParentTaskId
Name
Category
DueDate
OtherProperties
```

I was trying to do this with a 3rd class which contains

```
Date
List<Task>
```

Comment: Does it have to be editable or just read-only?

Comment: Rachel the control you are looking for is not really a grid, have a look at XtraScheduler from DevExpress or similar control from Telerik

Comment: If you want to use a DataGrid you'll need to prepare the proper collection: the outer join of Categories and 7 weekdays, null for the empty spots. You can use LINQ to create it.

Comment: @whatknott Users have to be able to double-click a cell to enter/edit a Task

Comment: @Davide I have looked at Telerik's Scheduler but it was slow, obnoxious to use, and I couldn't get it to do what I wanted. If I REALLY can't come up with anything I'll give it another go, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: So is day a property of TaskDayModel?  Is there a master list of tasks?

Comment: cool mock-up! how did you make that?

Comment: @Berryl Balsamiq: http://balsamiq.com/ I'd highly recommend it

Comment: @BalamBalam I added the current data structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have found a way to do it... I need to rearrange my Data a bit

- My main ViewModel will contain `ObservableCollection<DateTime> CurrentWeek` and `ObservableCollection<Category> CurrentTasks`
- The `Category` class should have `ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks`
- And `Task` should have `ObservableCollection<TaskInstances> Occurences`

The main ViewModel should also subscribe to `CurrentWeek.CollectionChanged`, and based on what the dates are in the collection, update each `Category.Task[x].Occurences` if `Category.Task.IsRecurring == true`

Then I think I can use the following structure to get what I want. I'll update this post when I know if this works or not

**Update:** It works :)

[image: Sample Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with a DataTable property that you rebuild when you change weeks, then bind a DataGrid to that DataTable.

Rebuild code would look something like this (will obviously need tweaking based on your collection properties):

```
tbl = new DataTable();
foreach(var day in Week) {
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(day.Name, Task));
}

foreach(var cat in Categories) {
    var tasks = AllTasks.Where(t => t.Category.equals(cat) && Week.Contains(t.Day));
    if (tasks.Any()) {
        foreach (var task in tasks) { 
            var row = new DataRow();
            row.SetField(day.Name, task);
            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could bind a DataGrid to that DataTable:

```
<!-- Wherever you want the datagrid -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header={Binding Columns[0].Name} CellTemplate="{StaticResource TaskTemplate}"/>
        <!-- Six more columns for the other days -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that we are talking about WPF, I assume that `Viewed Week`, `Categories`, and the `Tasks` are objects of the model. So what I would do in this case, is to create ModelView that combines that objects based on your app logic relationship into another ModelView's `Week` object, whom properties actually end up binded to actual UI (Grid, ListView, Telerik control, whatever...).

Comment: They are separate properties, which are currently stored in a `TaskDayModel`, however I can't for the life of me think of how to layout the control(s) to get the view I want. Maybe something will come to me when I come back tomorrow morning....

Comment: @Rachel. The point is they are separated properties. So you use one, let's call it SuperClass, in ModelView to put/get data from view, where actually that separated properties are visualized together, as much as I understood.